# How to Login User from AZURE AD in asp net core web api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm Developing an API which have single Sign-On Features (Google, Microsoft, Facebook).
I'm facing an issue to authenticate the user with Microsoft Azure AD.

I have configured Azure Portal and middleware.

```
   services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(APIConfig.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(APIConfig.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I Have a Login ActionMethod which have following code.

if API Parameter pass `{loginby = 4}` then i need to redirect to microsoft login page for authentication just like i did for google i don't want to put authorize attribute.

```
  if (userView.LoginBy == (int)UserLoginBy.MicrosoftAzure)
                    {

????? what to place here to redirect to microsoft account for user login
                    }


if (model.LoginBy == (int)UserLoginBy.Google)
        {

            string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly};
            string ApplicationName = Constant.ApplicationName;

            UserCredential credential;

            // string credPath = "credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = Constant.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = Constant.ClientSecret
                },
                Scopes,
                model.Email,
                CancellationToken.None).Result;
            
            model.ExternalAccountToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
            model.ExternalAccountRefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
            model.Email = credential.UserId;
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
           });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow;

- Before going to authenticate with AZURE AD make sure that you have Register an application with AZURE AD and provide the below in your `appsettings.json` file.

For example:-

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    //"Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
    "TenantId": "72xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "69xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "http://localhost:5204/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

- *Then We need to specify various scopes for our APIs if we are working with multiple projects or Microservices because the scope is necessary for authorizing the API, such as read and write access.
  For that, choose the Azure _Auth application's Expose an API option. The popup to create the scopes will appear when you click the + Add Scope button.*

For complete setup please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Enable authentication in your own web API by using Azure AD B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient)
- **BLOG**|[***Enable Azure AD Authentication Using .Net 5.0 Web API***](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-azure-ad-authentication-using-net-5-0-web-api/)